# ViewPager only handling fling gesture but let other MotionEvents be handled by fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-appcompat, gesturedetector

I'm using `ViewPager` from compat. One of the pages is a map which can be dragged/scrolled/panned (whatever it's called).

With original ViewPager, almost every horizontal move in the map causes unwanted paging to previous/next page, only when there is a vertical component in the move, then panning the map works.

What I'd like: The **ViewPager should only handle fling gestures** (and consume them) and let all other events pass to the controls on the fragments.

#### What I've tried so far

My currently best solution: **overwriting `ViewPager.canScroll`**:

```
@Override
protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
    if (v instanceof MapView) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
}
```

Disadvantage: When flinging through the pages, it stops when arriving on the map-page and map is flinging (unwanted).

**Next try: using a `GestureDetector`**. This sounds good, but I haven't managed it to work properly. I suppose one of the issues is my wrong implementation, especially regarding `onInterceptTouchEvent`.
I've tried so many things (returning true, false, calling super-methods), but it doesn't work smoothly (or not at all).

```
public class FlingableViewPager extends ViewPager {

private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetector;

public FlingableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}
public FlingableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    GestureListener gestureListener = new GestureListener();
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, gestureListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true; // super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true; // super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

private void movePage(int direction) {
    Log.d(TAG, "movePage " + direction);
    int currentItem = getCurrentItem();
    if (direction < 0) {
        if (currentItem > 0) {
            setCurrentItem(currentItem - 1);
        }
    } else {
        int items = getAdapter().getCount();
        if (currentItem < items - 1) {
            setCurrentItem(currentItem + 1);
        }
    }
}

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 150;

private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            movePage(1);
            return false; // Right to left
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            movePage(-1);
            return false; // Left to right
        }
        return false;
    }

}

}
```

I'm sorry. There are a lot of similar questions, but none helped to solve this problem.